# Potential energy in an expanding universe

Tags: astrophysics

A question you wonderful geniuses can hopefully answer. Imagine a piece of string drawn between two galaxies. Space between the galaxies is expanding. What force is being applied to the string? Where is the energy generating this force coming from (re: conservation of energy)? Does there exist tension like that between two points in space that are getting further away from each other as result of expansion?